# cURL command in smartsheet

Tags: curl, terminal, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-java-sdk-v2

when I use the following curl command: (the tokens are invalid don't worry)

```
curl https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/5848367060424580 -H "Authorization: Bearer 21txb6n2silf6dhsil8g9jxtdu" | python -m json.tool
```

I get a bunch of data looking like this:

```
 {
        "id": 1888886872926084,
        "index": 0,
        "primary": true,
        "title": "Primary Column",
        "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": 6392486500296580,
        "index": 1,
        "title": "Column2",
        "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": 4140686686611332,
        "index": 2,
        "title": "Column3",
        "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": 8644286313981828,
        "index": 3,
        "title": "Column4",
        "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": 481511989372804,
        "index": 4,
        "title": "Column5",
        "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
        "width": 150
    },
    {
        "id": 4985111616743300,
        "index": 5,
        "title": "Column6",
        "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
        "width": 150
    }
],
"createdAt": "2016-07-07T14:44:38Z",
"dependenciesEnabled": false,
"effectiveAttachmentOptions": [
    "FILE",
    "ONEDRIVE",
    "GOOGLE_DRIVE",
    "EVERNOTE",
    "BOX_COM",
    "EGNYTE",
    "DROPBOX"
],
"ganttEnabled": false,
"id": 5848567060424580,
"modifiedAt": "2016-07-07T15:22:53Z",
"name": "JagTestSheet",
"permalink": "https://app.smartsheet.com/b/home?lx=PoM3LKb9HF6g_jsJ9JoWwg",
"resourceManagementEnabled": false,
"rows": [
    {
        "cells": [
            {
                "columnId": 1888886872926084,
                "displayValue": "234",
                "value": 234.0
            },
            {
                "columnId": 6392486500296580,
                "displayValue": "657",
                "value": 657.0
            },
            {
                "columnId": 4140686686611332,
                "displayValue": "875",
                "value": 875.0
            },
            {
                "columnId": 8644286313981828
            },
            {
                "columnId": 481511989372804
            },
            {
                "columnId": 4985111616743300
            }
        ],
```

Now, I know its showing every row of data for the columns that are filled, but i wanted to know if there is anyway i could simplify this only to spit out what i need, for example only displayValue for the columns in which data are in ? Any help would be awesome thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a programming language to logically manipulate the data that is coming back from Smartsheet. I would recommend doing this with one of the existing SDK's that Smartsheet offers. Smartsheet currently has SDK's for Java, C#, Javascript, Python and PHP all listed on [this page](https://www.smartsheet.com/developers/sdks).

That said, you can also accomplish this task with bash using curl, grep, cut or jq.

First you can you `grep` to limit the result to only displayValue.

```
curl -s https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/5848367060424580 -H "Authorization: Bearer 21txb6n2silf6dhsil8g9jxtdu" | python -m json.tool | grep displayValue
```

Then you can take this a step further and only display the values by using `cut`:

```
curl -s https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/5848367060424580 -H "Authorization: Bearer 21txb6n2silf6dhsil8g9jxtdu" | python -m json.tool | grep displayValue | cut -d: -f2
```

---

You could also use a tool such as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) which has the ability to work with json output. You could use a command like the following to fetch only the displayValue.

```
curl -s https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/5848367060424580 -H "Authorization: Bearer 21txb6n2silf6dhsil8g9jxtdu" | jq '.rows[].cells[].displayValue'
```

Then you can take this a step further and remove the null results:

```
curl -s https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/5848367060424580 -H "Authorization: Bearer 21txb6n2silf6dhsil8g9jxtdu" | jq '.rows[].cells[] | select(.displayValue != null).displayValue'
```

Comment: I am trying these methods using curl, and they are not processing in the terminal. Any special thing i have to do before using these commands?

Comment: Extra data: line 1 column 17 - line 2 column 1 (char 16 - 24) <--- thats the response i get when i use the cut command with grep

Comment: @Jsant Try the commands now. I Added the `python` command to format the output before using grep. If you want to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) you will need to download and install it.